# Failing to generate proxy from WSDL in VS2017

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL that I try to generate a client proxy from within Visual Studio 2017.

1. Right click project name (WinForm)
2. Add > Service Reference
3. Paste WSDL adr
4. Click OK

Now I got 1 error and 20 warnings

Error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service
>   reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Please check other error and warning
>   messages for
>   details.  WindowsFormsApp1    c:\users\Me\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Connected
>   Services\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap   1

Warnings(some of them)

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail: There
>   was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent
>   on. XPath to wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='MyTest.GetInformation:v2']/wsdl:binding[@name='GetInformationBinding']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='MyTest.GetInformation:v2']/wsdl:service[@name='GetInformationService']/wsdl:port[@name='GetInformationPort'] WindowsFormsApp1    c:\users\Me\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Connected
>   Services\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There
>   was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is
>   dependent on. XPath to wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='MyTest.GetInformation:v2']/wsdl:portType[@name='GetInformationInterface']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='MyTest.GetInformation:v2']/wsdl:binding[@name='GetInformationBinding']   WindowsFormsApp1    c:\users\Me\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Connected
>   Services\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail: An
>   exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: The datatype
>   'MyTest.attentionSignal:v1:II' is
>   missing. XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='MyTest.GetInformation:v2']/wsdl:portType[@name='GetInformationInterface']    WindowsFormsApp1    c:\users\Me\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Connected
>   Services\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap   1

SoapUI 5.3.0 can generate proxy from the same WSDL and I can also genereate it by using Web Reference (compability mode 2.0) in VS2017. The later solution do however not work for me becouse I have code from v1 of this WSDL that I want to reuse.

Edit :

Here is the WSDL, add it as a service referece in VS 2017 and you should see the problem : 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AskujIssKpne6170QEQdCLrkG8-u

Answer (score -2):

- you should download wsdl locally using browser then follow your rest
  steps
- Right click project name (WinForm)
- Add > Service Reference
- Paste WSDL local path and Click OK

Update :
If above way is not working.You can try another way 
 - Create web proxy by XSD.exe using below command

```
wsdl.exe [path To Your WSDL File] //in visual studio command line
```

- That will generate proxy classes which you can copy/move to your project and use it.

Comment: The first try was to add service reference from the local WSDL files, when this did not work I tried to host the WSDL in IIS(becouse this was what I hade to to a couple of years ago). None of the methods works with this WSDL. It is however validate OK with XML Spy and it works in SOAPUI. Only way to get it working in Visual Studio is to use compability mode but it feels wrong to use .NET 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I have tied that but it uses the compability mode from what I can see?

Comment: @Banshee what do you mean by "I have tied that but it uses the compability mode from what I can see" ?

Comment: wsdl seems to generate the same code as If i choose the compability mode from within add servicereference in VS, so it is based on .NET 2.0. I was hoping on either be able to prove that the WSDL faulted or add it as a service reference in VS as any other modern WSDL.

Comment: Have you tried "unchecking" the "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" in Configure service reference option ?

Comment: Yes, the Error List shows : Custom tool error: Fialed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceRef1'. Pleas check other error and warningmessages for details. The same Custom tool errors/warnings is shown and the ServiceRef1 is empty, no client proxy. The app.config is also not updated with WCF settings.

Comment: I have now updated my post with the URL to the WSDL, pleas, try it.